# Refreshing screen on a bad way led to application performance issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, task

This is how my system works:

2 computers are using different application but same database (Table: Orders).

1st computer is making orders and writing them to database, 
2nd computer need to display new orders every 5 seconds.

I will shortly describe (to avoid long text) what I need to achieve and how I did it right now :

- 2nd computers application need "to go to database" every 5 seconds to check for new orders and show them on screen

And when there is a lot orders and when I'm doing this pretty often my application is crashing down.

This is how my app works right now:

```
public MainWindow()
{

    try
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
       this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
       //When app runs for first time get all orders
       var ordersList = OrdersController.GetOrders();


       collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
       collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("NumberOfOrder"));
       DataContext = collectionViewSource;

       //Here I'm refreshing screen every 5 seconds




 DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
       timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
       timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
       timer.Start();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Every 5 seconds get all orders from database
    var ordersList = OrdersController.GetOrders();
    collectionViewSource.Source = null;

    collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
    DataContext = collectionViewSource;
}
```

`GetOrders` method:

```
public static List<Orders> GetOrders()
{
            DataServices.DB.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, DataServices.DB.Orders);

            var results = DataServices.DB.proc_Orders_GetAll().ToList();

            List<Orders> localOrders = new List<Orders>();

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Orders local = new Orders();
                local.Sender = item.Sender;
                local.Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Quantity);
                local.ArticleTitle = item.ArticleTitle;
                local.DateOfOrder = Convert.ToDateTime(item.DateOfOrder);
                lokalnen.Add(local);
            }
            return localOrders;
}
```

But this code above is not so good, it's causing crushing of my application if there's a lot orders..
Probably because UI is rendering all the time again and again

Moving this "refresh job" to another task might solve the issue, so I tried something like this:

First of all create new method `RefreshScreen` which might look like this:

```
private void RefreshScreen()
{
  var ordersList = OrdersController.GetOrders();
  collectionViewSource.Source = null;

  collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
  DataContext = collectionViewSource;
}
```

And I moved this `RefreshScreen()` to a new task like this:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Instead old code where I set source of my list and of my datagrid directlly in timer tick now I moved it to new method and calling that method from a new task
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RefreshScreen())
        .ContinueWith(task =>
   {

   }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

}
```

But this is again making my app crushs after a while...
I really don't know how to solve this, maybe something with Observablle collections or whatever,
I don't know...

Any kind of help would be awesome and great to prevent my app from crushing!
Thanks !

Edit : after running app from my visual studio I get this after few seconds (with solution that is including task in timer tick ):

[image]

[image]

Comment: @mjwills simply there's popup message with some error after a while and after I click ok application shuts down. And I realized that happen if I click somewhere on UI while refresh is in progress..

Comment: @mjwills 
I'll try to make that error happen, so I might show you, but it's not showing up all the time,
but I know what is happening all the time: application is very slow, because of often resfreshing/rendering UI I guess...

Comment: How does the application crash? Does it just hang or are you getting an exception? What does the exception message say?

Comment: If application crashes with popup - go to windows Event Viewer and find corresponding event which will contain more information about crash source.

Comment: @mm8 It's just like Application.exe has stopped working

Windows can check online for solution to the problem ...
Close application ... For example if I click on some other button to check for something else app slown down because probably it refreshing in that time (setting source to my datagrid ) is there way to solve this somehow?

Comment: Fetch fewer items from the database and make sure that UI virtualization is enabled.

Comment: @mm8 There is now real exception, check for my edit please. and please suggest me if this is good solution with tasks, maybe I should do it with tasks or ? But for now this seems fine solution to me, to refresh gui without freezing/slowing app :/

Comment: You can't access DataContext property or any other property of a UI element from a background thread. That's why you get the "the calling thread cannot access.." exception.

Comment: @mm8 so what's solution here to keep ui responsive while I'm refreshing (getting new items from database) ? :/

Comment: Fetch the items on a background thread and update the UI once the query has returned.

Comment: @mm8 could you please provide an example of that? how that might look..

Answer (score 0):

You should query the database on a background thread but you can't access `DataContext` property or any other property of a UI element from a background thread. That's why you get the "The calling thread cannot access.." exception.

You could try to start a `Task` that calls the `GetOrders()` method on a background thread:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return OrdersController.GetOrders()
    }).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        collectionViewSource.Source = task.Result;
        DataContext = collectionViewSource;
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

But if it is the code that runs in the `ContinueWith` delegate once the query has completed that is slow, you have no other option than to fetch fewer records.

You should also make sure that you haven't disabled the UI virtualization. You might also want to try without grouping the results. This may be slow as well.

Comment: orderList is not recognized there, it should be declared as a global list?

Comment: Sorry, the Source property should be set to the Result of the Task. I edited the answer.

Comment: This code seems to work, but anyway I'm wondering is it possible to 
     make this app more faster, what I mean here: when I'm scrolling down and app is refreshed everything slows down, and scrolling is suddenly lagging.
     I'm not running away from changing whole concept if I could make it more functional..

Answer (score -2):

Try implementing SignalR. Works pretty well for that kind of operations